# Closing InputStream for MIDI

Tags: java, stream, midi, javasound

When should one close an `InputStream` that was passed as a parameter to the MIDI Sequencer?
Does it get closed automatically when `Sequencer.close()` is called, or should I close the input stream once it has been read into the sequencer?

```
public MidiSound(InputStream in) throws MidiUnavailableException,
        IOException, InvalidMidiDataException {
    sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    receiver = MidiSystem.getReceiver();

    sequencer.open();
    synth.open();
    sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(receiver);
    sequencer.setSequence(in);
    //in.close()?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `InputStream` (all I/O, pretty much) requires closing.

If you use Java 7, you can use the new "try-with-resources" syntax.

E.g.,

```
try (AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url))
{   
    //audio handling here
}
```

With this syntax, there is no need to explicitly close the newly defined `AudioInputStream` in a `finally` block. The Java runtime will do it automatically. This syntax can be used with any I/O type that implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.

I just learned about this two weeks ago. I'm reading "Java Programming -- Learn Advanced Skills from a Java Expert" by Poornachandra Sarang, Oracle Press 2012. I've been really impressed with this book!

Comment: Does this apply to MIDI as well? Java seems to have a different library for MIDI files

Comment: OK, I just looked up MidiDeviceReceiver in the API spec. It extends Receiver which in turn extends AutoCloseable. My guess is that AutoCloseable's presence indicates that there are resources that can and SHOULD be closed. Otherwise, why would it be there? There is some text in MidiDevice API that talks about closing as well; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiDevice.html   Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, AutoCloseable's api states: "A resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html